# Sony Xperia L1 Screen Always Open, I Cannot Lock

Tags: lock-screens, sony-xperia-l

I have a Xperia L1. When I press lock button, the screen locked and re-opened in 2 seconds every time. I cannot find the fix for it. Are anyone encountered with this issue ? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Proximity sensor seems broken due to service report. After a fix, it resolved. Thanks.